# AWS RDS Automated backup AZ zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

AWS RDS backups for single az instance are stored in an s3 bucket managed by AWS (not visible to user) as per documentation.

My question is for a single az instance, is the automated backup that is taken only stored in that specific AZ instance, or since it is stored in an s3 bucket managed by AWS, region-specific, not az specific?

Answer (score 0):

By default S3 is a global service. All data is replicated in >=3 AZ. Therefore, your backups are stored in multiple AZs.
Also, S3 provides different availability classes. For example, you can set for  your S3 bucket a class "One Zone-IA" and then all data will be stored in one AZ. You should look into bucket settings to get know which class is turned on.
Also S3 provdies different classes for different objects in one bucket. Therefore, pay attention to backup-file settings in S3 too.

Link: https://aws.amazon.com/en/s3/storage-classes

Comment: "All data is replicated in >=3 AZ" is correct. Saying it is a global service implies it is also replicated to multiple regions, which is false. And all the rest of your answer related to storage class, etc. is not a correct answer to this question, because the RDS snapshot is stored in an S3 bucket managed by AWS that you have no access to, so you can't do things like change the storage class.

Comment: Yes I understand for an S3 bucket the options. The RDS snapshot stored by AWS in its own managed s3 bucket, is that across the AZs as well or is that just in the one AZ that the RDS instance is in?

Answer (score 0):

The automated snapshots stored in S3 are replicated across 3 more more AZs. If you need more than that, you can look into the [AWS Backup](https://aws.amazon.com/backup/) service. AWS Backup can do things like immutable backups in a protected vault, and cross-region replication of your backups.

Comment: Thanks for this - is there any documentation from AWS that supports this, or is this just because S3 buckets are region specific